# Click a hidden element via hover or any way to click the button

Tags: selenium

A button pops out after hovering thru the row , what I want is to click the delete button. What happens with my code is nothing but it does not produce any error.

Tried hover then selecting and hover then click hidden class

```
WebDriverWait waitPOSCashCollect = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        waitPOSCashCollect.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pageModule));
        driver.findElement(pageModule).click();
        System.out.println("Successful in proceeding to POS Cash Collect Page");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;

        Actions hover = new Actions(driver);

        WebElement Elem_to_hover = driver.findElement(By.className("imgdel"));

        hover.moveToElement(Elem_to_hover);

        hover.build();

        hover.perform();
```

HTML

```
<tbody><tr class="tableheader" align="center"><td class="tdwid"></td><td>类<br>Type</td><td>总数<br>Total Amt</td><td>最后修改员<br>Last Modified By</td><td>日期<br>Date</td><td class="tddelete_header"></td></tr><tr contextmenu="rgb(214, 242, 255)" style="background-color: rgb(214, 242, 255); cursor: pointer;"><td class="tablerow tdwid"><span class="txtwid">100000000000015</span></td><td class="tablerow tdtype tdclick"><span class="spntype">Cash Beginning 初始现金</span></td><td class="tablerow tdtotalamount tdclick"><span class="spntotalamount">1,000.00</span></td><td class="tablerow tdlastmodifiedby tdclick"><span class="spnlastmodifiedby">superadmin</span></td><td class="tablerow tddatetimemodified tdclick"><span class="spndatetimemodified">2019-09-27 13:57:27</span></td><td class="tablerow tddelete"><img class="imgdel" style="display: none;" onclick="delete_fnc(this)" src="images/icondelete.png"></td></tr><tr contextmenu="rgb(255, 255, 255)" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: pointer;"><td class="tablerow tdwid"><span class="txtwid">100000000000016</span></td><td class="tablerow tdtype tdclick"><span class="spntype">Cash Beginning 初始现金</span></td><td class="tablerow tdtotalamount tdclick"><span class="spntotalamount">10.00</span></td><td class="tablerow tdlastmodifiedby tdclick"><span class="spnlastmodifiedby">superadmin</span></td><td class="tablerow tddatetimemodified tdclick"><span class="spndatetimemodified">2019-09-27 14:41:00</span></td><td class="tablerow tddelete"><img class="imgdel" style="display: none;" onclick="delete_fnc(this)" src="images/icondelete.png"></td></tr></tbody>
```

Also tried this

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tbl\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/img"));
```

Comment: Did you try javascript click on the element?

Comment: Tried it but I think I did it wrong this is what i did ( Actions action = new Actions(driver);action.moveToElement(elementToHover).click(elementToClick).build().perform();)

Comment: am I getting it right? in your code, first you wait for your item to become visible( clickable) and then you try to hover the mouse on the element to make the other element visible?

Comment: if you hover on the row , a hidden delete button will pop out , which I wan to click after hovering on the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code using Actions class,

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement deleteButton= driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@onclick='delete_fnc(this)']));
actions.moveToElement(deleteButton);
actions.click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make the element visible first.

And you can use Actions to click it.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display='block';", element);
```

or

Click by Javascript directly.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```